Using Seperate XYZ node with Position attribute
I am trying to build a geometry node modifier that will display the position coordinates for each point of a mesh.  My thought is to use an Instance on Points node with String to Curves as instances.  The string values will be composed of the x, y and z coordinates for each point.  Here is my node setup:

Here is the result:

I know that the red dotted lines are where the problem lies.  They seem to indicate that I am providing multiple values while the Value to String node is expecting a single value.  I just can't figure out why the Separate XYZ node is outputting multiple values for X, Y and Z.  What am I missing?
Thanks!

you can search for "blender geometry nodes indexviewer". There are a lot of them on yt. here just one example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAiKVZyYUKU this should help you how to do it

According your actual experience, may I recommend to start with something like this : how to display point index next to the point?. There is another post about rendering floats, but I could not find it right now...

Apart from the helpful links provided above, for the simple question at the end to why the Separate XYZ node is putting out multiple values there is a simple answer: you use a Capture Attribute to get the positions of a cube's points. A cube has at least (like yours) 8 vertices. And 8 positions are multiple positions, aren't they? And the  Value to String can only convert one value, not 8 at a time.

Here is a second reference to visualize numerical values : Random values to string on each instance in Geometry Nodes?
